# What's the difference between i386, armv7 and armv7s?

Tags: xcode

I would like to know the difference between those architectures in Xcode because I need to know how I understand that a library can compile correctly for iOS Simulator and also for iPhone 5, iPhone 4s and iPhone 4. Or just for one of those.

Comment: The IDE is called Xcode... Not XCode, xCode or anything else ;)

Comment: Thx I made a mistake typing the name.. :D

Answer (score 7):

- **i386:** Typically MacOSX (I am not sure whether Simulator is included here or no).
- **arm6:** old iPhones.
- **arm7:** iPhone4/4S.
- **arm7s:** additional instructions for arm7 to make good use of iPhone 5 processor.

Hope this helps. Compiling libraries to support all platforms sometimes is very frustrating and tedious task. Good luck!

Comment: Simulator does run in the i386 of the Mac system.

Comment: @OwenHartnett so does it mean that if i386 is missing from 'valid architectures' in Xcode I cannot compile or run in the simulator? If that is the case, why in my project I have set 'ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BITS' (armv7 and armv7s) and I can run and compile for the simulator?

Comment: It will do the right thing to run on the simulator. If you are using third party libraries that don't have an i386 slice, then the libraries won't run on the simulator.  You can set the "Supported Platforms" to iphonesimulator or iphoneos in your target, and your target won't run on the one you didn't set.