# Xcode: What do the values for VALID_ARCHS (Valid Architectures) mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

In the [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW85), we can see that the identifier `VALID_ARCHS` can take various values as listed like - `i386`, `armv6`, etc.

What do each of them specifically mean? If they are already explained somewhere then please provide the link.

Comment: They are different CPU architectures

Comment: Yes, but if I want to set one to 64-bit target for instance, then which one should I choose?

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174189/whats-the-difference-between-i386-armv7-and-armv7s

Comment: That's where the confusion starts. I have set it to `x86_64` and it is compiling it for 64-bit target. So, what is now the difference between `armv7s` and `x86_64`?

Comment: x86_64 for 64bit mac and armv7s for 64bit iphone

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to know the meanings of other values? Are they mentioned somewhere?

Comment: check the link i posted above

Comment: Yeah, I think armv7s is still 32-bit. arm64 is the first 64-bit one.